# Plane waves intensity

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation

Our professor said that a plane wave has the same intensity in the plane perpendicular to it's propagation. I can't really make sense of how that is possible. I mean, shouldn't the intensity decrease as we move away from the wave?

Comment: Imagine a plane wave as a wall of light. The figures [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave) might help you to picture it.

Comment: To get a 'real' plane wave would require a source with infinite dimensions - then, yes, you have constant intensity vs. propagation distance (the math works out just fine). Just like the difference in field between a point charge and an infinite sheet of charge.

Comment: I get that the power distribution and intensity remains same at one wave front, but I cant understand why it would not decrease as we move away from the wave

Comment: Because you *can't* move away from a plane wave.  A plane wave is an idealization.  It has infinite and uniform extent in directions perpendicular to the direction of propagation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier if you start with a one-dimensional "line" wave.  Imagine, for example, a wave moving across a lake.  the crest (peak) of the wave has the same intensity everywhere in a line along the wave, which is a line perpendicular to the direction of propagation. The trough similarly has the same depth everywhere. Now imagine that wave propagating without dispersing (i.e. it holds its shape). No matter where you measure it, it'll have the same peak value along that line perpendicular to its direction of motion.

In 3-D, it's the same for the plane perpendicular to the direction of motion, except that you have to treat the intensity as a "fourth dimension" rather than a displacement of something physical like the water's surface.